# Configure Robotic Library with BackupExec 12

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, backup-exec

Anyone have experience configuring a 24tape robotic library with BackupExec 12? Just need some input on how I should schedule the backup jobs and whether I should create library partitions. Any advice would be great. Thanks.

Comment: A bit more detail on what you are backing up (total size) andwhat retention you want would help.

Comment: I am backing up the company produced media (raw pictures, audio, video) so the size will bloom up when they start uploading more files to the server.  So I am planning to use all 32TB of storage with 4 weeks retention.